# Deregister nextgen on shopp pages

Tags: plugin-shopp

Ok, I have a site using Netgen Gallery and Shopp.  I'm trying to deregister the nextgen styles and scripts on the shopp products and pages as there is a conflict.  My shopp page title is "Registration" and I'd like to stop any Nextgen stuff from loading on any shopp pages.

Here's the code (that didn't work) that I added to my functions.php

```
// NextGEN script exclusions
add_action('wp_print_scripts','my_deregister_javascript', 100);
function my_deregister_javascript(){
if ($post->post_parent == registration) {
    wp_deregister_script('ngg_script');
    wp_deregister_script('thickbox');
}
}

// NextGEN style exclusions
add_action('wp_print_styles','my_deregister_styles', 100);
function my_deregister_styles(){
if ($post->post_parent == registration) {
    wp_deregister_style('NextGEN');
    wp_deregister_style('thickbox');
}
}
```

Does anyone see what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Change `$post->post_parent == registration` to `is_page( 'registration' )`, and use `wp_enqueue_scripts` instead of `wp_print_scripts/styles`.